# Autodesk Forge Data Visualization Quickstart Terminal Command Question

Tags: data-visualization, autodesk-forge

I'm fairly new to this type of development, and I am attempting to follow this guide: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/quickstart/replace_model/#using-forge-storage.

I'm using Windows 10, and as I was working on this tutorial, it came to my attention that the cp command is a Linux operation that doesn't exist in Windows. I was able to work around this, but I'm unsure of what the next command, > ENV=local npm run dev, is trying to accomplish and how I could complete this in Windows. It seems that this is supposed to initialize the environment variables I set in the env_template.env file in the previous steps, though I don't know if I'm understanding it correctly. Thus, my question is what is this command doing, and how do I recreate it in Windows?

Apologies if this question is poorly worded or if I'm using incorrect terminology. As i said, I'm a bit new to this type of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the inconvenience. Here are a couple of ways we used to help our accelerator attendees.

1. Powershell

```sh
$env:ENV="local";npm run dev
```

2. Command Prompt

```sh
set ENV=local && npm run dev

//OR
setx ENV "local" && npm run dev
```

3. `lanch.json` of VS Code debugger

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            //"program": "${workspaceFolder}/server/localserver.js",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/server/.env",
            "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "run-script", "dev"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```